# How can I troubleshoot Smart Narrative not recognizing certain measures in the value section?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I am using Smart Narrative for the text summary, in that I am trying to put numbers that are getting calculated in measures.

But when I am putting those measures in value, some of the measures are getting recognized by Smart Narrative but some are not.
What is the reason behind that?

I tried to put measure in value section of Smart Narrative but some measures are not been recognized.

Measure being recognized->

```
CY USG = 
 var PY_TO=CALCULATE([TO Data],SAMEPERIODLASTYEAR('Calendar'[Date]))
var CY_TO=[TO_Data]
var Acq_TO=TOTALQTD(SUM('Finance Source'[Acq TO Data]),'Calendar'[Date])
var Dis_TO=TOTALQTD(SUM('Finance Source'[Dis TO Data]),'Calendar'[Date])
return IF(ISBLANK(PY_TO),BLANK(),DIVIDE((CY_TO-Acq_TO),(PY_TO-Dis_TO))-1)
```

Measure not recognized ->

```
TO Contri BG = 
var to_bg=[TO Data]

var to_ul=CALCULATE([TO Data],ALL(Data_BG))

return DIVIDE(to_bg,to_ul)
```

Comment: Can you give examples of the measures not being recognized?

Comment: @Luke_0 I have added both (Measure recognized and measure not recognized) in the question

Comment: From the documentation, percentage of grand total measures are not supported. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/visuals/power-bi-visualization-smart-narrative#considerations-and-limitations Hard to say how you could work around this without seeing your dataset

Comment: @Luke_0 
I am doing the same in the recognized measure as well, there also I am dividing and the measure format is the percentage.
But this issue isn't happening for that measure